# Trying to build a table dynamically in Angular

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HeXWDrDkpZefcvA1zexx?p=preview) I have a directive with a table. I'm trying to add dynamically to the table one row with two cells. Still, the table is showing only one cell. What's wrong with this code?

Javascript

```
angular.module('app', []);


angular.module('app')
.directive('directive1', function() {


    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.scope = true;

    directive.template = '<table class="c" border="1"></table>';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

                var t = angular.element(".c");
                var r1 = t.append("<tr></tr>");
                var col1 = r1.append("<td></td>");
                col1.text("1111");
                var col2 = r1.append("<td></td>");
                col2.text("2222");

    };

    return directive;

});
```

Comment: Actually it isn't creating any cell, you can check it *inspecting* the generated HTML.

Comment: I know, but how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work as well:

```
var t = angular.element(".c");
var r1 = t.append(angular.element(document.createElement('tr')));
var col1 =angular.element(document.createElement('td')).html("1111");
var col2 =angular.element(document.createElement('td')).html("2222");
r1.append(col1);
r1.append(col2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
            var t = angular.element(".c");
            var r1 = $("<tr></tr>")
            t.append(r1);
            var col1 = $("<td></td>");
            r1.append(col1);
            col1.text("1111");
            var col2 = $("<td></td>");
            r1.append(col2);
            col2.text("2222");
```